# NodeJS and PostgreSQL function returns tuple, not row

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm running PostgreSQL and NodeJS.

In PostgreSQL I have a custom function `dummy`:

```
... RETURNS RECORD AS $$
    ...
    DECLARE ret RECORD
    ...
    RETURN ret;

  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In NodeJS this returns a `tuple`, as a `string`:

```
(x,y,z)
```

So I have to manually split the string and read the parts...
Is it possible to have PostgreSQL return the `tuple` as a `row`or similar, so I can use `data.x`, `data.y` and `data.z`in NodeJS instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

fn():

```
t=# create or replace function f() returns record as $$ declare ret record; begin for ret in (select oid::int,datname::text from pg_database limit 1) loop return ret; end loop; end; $$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

your call:

```
t=# select f();
        f
------------------
 (13505,postgres)
(1 row)
```

expected call:

```
t=# select * from f() as r(o int,n text);
   o   |    n
-------+----------
 13505 | postgres
(1 row)
```

and if you want to predefine the structure of record to be called implicitely, you can create a dummy fn():

```
t=# create or replace function dummy() returns table (a int,b text) as $$ begin return query select * from f() as r(o int,n text); end; $$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# select * from dummy();
   a   |    b
-------+----------
 13505 | postgres
(1 row)
```

of if you want to avoid `FROM`:

```
t=# select (dummy()).*;
   a   |    b
-------+----------
 13505 | postgres
(1 row)
```

Comment: Works, thank you. Is it possible to embed that into the postgresql function instead, so users simply can query `select dummy()`?

Comment: My challenge is that `select * from f()`should be something like `select my-variable1, my-variable2` but that seems difficult.

Comment: Figured it out, apparently easy `SELECT my-variable1, my-variable2` actually worked.